# Why PostMessage MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN crashes the receiving application?

Tags: python, winapi

I am trying to **send a mouse click** (*a sequence of left button down and left button up events*) to a **window in the background** - for example to an application opened behind a browser. I am trying to do this via **Pywin32**, namely `win32api`, `win32gui` and `win32con` modules.

In my main function I get a handle to the window and call a clicking function:

```
def main():
    window = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "ExistingWindowName")
    while True:
        test_click_bg(window, 250, 250)
        sleep(1)
```

The function responsible for mouse clicks in the background is pretty simple:

```
def test_click_bg(window, x, y):
    win32gui.PostMessage(window, win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y)
    win32gui.PostMessage(window, win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x ,y)
```

Already the first call to `PostMessage` crashes the window I am trying to send this event to. Why is this happening? I tested with a Mozilla Firefox, Windows Snipping Tool and few other programs. All crashed.

I am fully capable of sending a mouse click to a window in the foreground through `win32api.mouse_event`, but that does not help me with sending a message to the windows in the background. Can it even be done?

Comment: You cannot do what you are trying to do. Even if you decided to send actual window messages (rather than flags used with a different API).

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for the answer. Can you please point me somewhere when can I read more about why I cannot do it? Also, the person who downvoted - what should have been better about the question to avoid the downvote?

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513), and [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903). Reason for the downvote: This code is purely based on guessing. An answer to a question that's asking why code doesn't do what its author guessed it should isn't going to be useful. If you insist on knowing: You are posting a message constant that expects pointers as one of its arguments. The victim tries to dereference them and crashes.

Comment: @IInspectable Fair enough! While it certainly is a result of guess-work, I did a whole lot of testing before coming with the question though. :) Thank you for the reference and I greatly appreciate the last part of your comment - it answers my question. If you are interested in putting it into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: The value of `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` is 2 so you are posting message with code 2. This is `WM_DESTROY`. Most applications when receive `WM_DESTROY` in main window procedure do some cleanup and exit.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but a solution to your immediate issue: Use a UI Automation library, like [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). UI Automation allows you to automate applications without faking input and without imposing the restriction to require the target application to be the foreground application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why PostMessage MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN crashes the receiving
>   application?

This question @Daniel Sęk has already answered:

> The value of MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN is 2 so you are posting message with
>   code 2. This is WM_DESTROY. Most applications when receive WM_DESTROY
>   in main window procedure do some cleanup and exit.

[`PostMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea#return-value) is used to send **WM_**xxxx type message instead of **MOUSEEVENTF_**xxxx.

> I am fully capable of sending a mouse click to a window in the
>   foreground through win32api.mouse_event, but that does not help me
>   with sending a message to the windows in the background. Can it even
>   be done?

For this issue, you can use `PostMessage` send [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown) message.

A side note: [mouse_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) function has been superseded. Use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.